# How to make GNU readline completion display and cycle completions

Tags: shell, autocomplete, terminal, readline

By default GNU readline will only display the relevant options

```
> a[tab]
abacus albatross avatar
```

setting `"TAB: menu-complete"` will automatically cycle trough options

```
> a[tab]
> abacus[tab]
> albatross
```

How can I make GNU readline behave like bash? First `tab` press would display all options, then it would cycle through available options?

```
> a[tab]
abacus albatross avatar
> a[tab]
abacus albatross avatar
> abacus
abacus albatross avatar
```